Proving NOT TRUE in Lambda Calculus
FALSE = λxy.y
TRUE = λxy.x
We can define the NOT operation as follows:
NOT = λx.x FALSE TRUE
I can prove NOT FALSE by doing this:
`NOT FALSE = λx.x (λxy.y) (λxy.x) (λxy.y)
 -  x = x
 -  M = x (λxy.y) (λxy.x)
 -  N = (λxy.y)

(λxy.y) (λxy.y) (λxy.x)
-   x = x
-   M = λy.y
-   N = λxy.y

λy.y {x --> λxy.y} = λy.y
(λy.y)(λxy.x)
-   x = y
-   M = y
-   N = λxy.x

y { y --> λxy.x) = λxy.x which is TRUE`
How can I prove NOT TRUE is FALSE using beta reductions?

You're missing parentheses to get the right precedence -- in particular, you should have NOT FALSE = (λx.x (λxy.y) (λxy.x)) (λxy.y)

I figured out the answer was to leave TRUE and FALSE as they were.
NOT TRUE = λx.x (λxy.y) (λxy.x) (λxy.x)
-   x = x
-   M = x (λxy.y) (λxy.x)
-   N = (λxy.y)

(λxy.x) (λxy.y) (λxy.x)
TRUE FALSE TRUE
(λxy.x) FALSE TRUE
-   x = x
-   M = λy.x
-   N = λxy.y

λy.x {x --> λxy.y} = λy.(λxy.y)
λy. (λxy.y) (λxy.x)
λy. FALSE TRUE
-   x = λy
-   M = λxy.y (FALSE)
-   N = λxy.x (TRUE)

FALSE {y --> (λxy.x)} = (λxy.y)
λxy.y which is False
